# iCloud Backup/Restore HTML5 Cordova App in iOS

Tags: ios, html, sqlite, cordova, cordova-ios

I am using Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin to store data locally in iOS device. I need to backup the data saved by the sqlite plugin to iCloud. I have searched net and tried various options without any success. Also, I found the following SO post saying that it is not possible in case of localStorage. [Can HTML5 localStorage in Cordova/Phonegap app be synced to iCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259821/can-html5-localstorage-in-cordova-phonegap-app-be-synced-to-icloud)

My question is, **is there any way to backup the data to iCloud while using Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin to store data?**

Please reply me if somebody has already done it. Or somebody has the same experience and can confidently say, *it is not possible* or *this is the way to do it*.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BackupWebStorage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/ios/config.html) preference for this purpose. You can 3 options `cloud`, `local` and `none`. To backup your data on iCloud you need to set BackupWebStorage value to `cloud`. By default it is `cloud`

From official docs:

> `BackupWebStorage` (string, either `none`, `local`, or the default `cloud`):
>   Set to cloud to allow web storage data to backup via iCloud. Set to
>   local to allow only local backups via iTunes sync. Set to none prevent
>   web storage backups.

Just to reconfirm, add below to `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
```