# I am wondering how my app accesses SQLLite database in ios App

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite, uitableview

Im am new to sqllite and databases in general, so far i have an app in which you enter data which is then stored on sqllite db file. I am only running on ios simulator so i am not sure how the actual app will work. Will the app still be able to fetch data and update the sql database when my computer is shut down? I guess my question is: is sqllite database also on the cloud or online somewhere.

Best Regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the file stored?

Comment: Yes it will work when your computer is shut down..because it saves in the phone in which your app is installed and for your 2nd question its not on cloud or online..you have to customise it to put on icloud.

Comment: SQLite is always a "local" database, resident on the box that implements the API.  So the DB file will be on the phone.  However, you need to beware of a common mistake:  While you can read a file from the "bundle", you cannot modify the bundle, so if you pre-create a SQLite file and place it in the bundle the file will go "poof" on you.  It needs to be copied from the bundle to read-write space before you use it, as a part of your install process.  (But if you simply create the file from scratch on first use, then you don't need to copy -- just be sure to use the right file path.)

Comment: (It should be mentioned that if you just need a simple database with no special features or abilities you should probably use Core Data instead of using SQLite directly.  Core Data is Apple's layer on top of SQLite that simplifies access to it.  Only use SQLite directly if you need features not supported by Core Data.)

Comment: ok thanks so much, i now understand that it will be on the app. I am making a chat app, will the iphone be able to update the database and then update the tableview with new messages like it is doing now on the simulator, the db file is in the resources folder

Comment: Hot Licks, So if i understand what you wrote, i can not modify the database which means that i couldn't update it, could you further specify the procedures to take? Thank you

Comment: You certainly can modify the database.  Just don't pre-install a database and expect it to work from the bundle -- it must be copied to a legit read/write directory.

Comment: ok thank you very much, could you please explain what pre-installing the database means, and what which read/write directory i should consider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use core data to work with iCloud.here is a nice documentation .

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Using iCloud with a SQLite database is possible only if your app uses Core Data to manage that database. Accessing live database files in iCloud using the SQLite interfaces is not supported and will likely corrupt your database. However, you can create a Core Data store based on SQLite as long as you follow a few extra steps when setting up your Core Data structures. You can also continue to use other types of Core Data stores—that is, stores not based on SQLite—without any special modifications.

courtesy:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799255/1865424

If you have any More issues regarding this..Happy to help you.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i am trying to avoid putting it in the cloud as much as possible, do you think it will be necessary for my application? I am making a chat app, and the database constitutes of messages

Comment: @OmarClinton  yes you have to put it on cloud whether it is iCloud or something other..so,that your users will be updated from anywhere they use it and it is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a file-based database stored in your app ( locally in the device ). To centralize the database, you should have server-side support. Recommend to use better DBMS like MySQL for more feature support.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you are only giving the name of the file when opening your database, it is stored on your device.  Each device has its own "sandbox" on  your device where its files get stored.

If you want to save your data to the cloud, that requires additional programming.

[Here is a good description in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2).

[Here is a description on how to use the cloud.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html)

Comment: thank you so much for the quick answer. will it be necessary to put it on the cloud. I am making a chat app and i am wondering if the database will be automatically updated once a message is sent on an iphone without using the cloud.

Comment: Using the iCloud is much safer for the user's data, as if anything happens to the user's device, the data will still be saved on the cloud.  Either way, if you save to the database, then commit/synchronize the database, your database will get updated.