# iOS and Databases

Tags: ios, database

I am creating an iPhone app where people will submit some text that will be submitted and stored so it can be viewed by other people who have the app.

I have absolutely zero experience with databases and have no idea where to start.

Can anyone tell me exactly what I need to know (mySQL, etc.) and suggest a path for me to take? Sorry if this is vague, but like I said, I have such little experience I don't even know what it is I need to learn.

Thanks in advanced, cheers.

Comment: A database will not solve the problem of making text submitted by one person viewable by another. A database only stores, organizes, and retrieves data. You need a way to communicate it.

Comment: read my answer and comments properly..I think this may help you..here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/17509236/1865424

Comment: you should read first about data base otherwise you will always asking about the basic things.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7WBmlK8GLo  this may help you..

Comment: To store data on the iPhone, you need core data. Next step is sharing that data to other iPhones, this requires a web-service (could build this with ruby on rails or php, once you have data storing on the device and equivalent data on the web service, you then build a synchronisation tool between them :) I've done this many times, there's a lot of technology to learn from start to finish but its fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, You have to use SQLite data base. generally developers has already created class file which they extends and use every time,  but as you are starting with Db. i would recommend you some link.

1>  [iOS - SQLite Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm)

2> [An Example SQLite based iOS 4 iPhone Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_4_iPhone_Application)

and the best one is below, I recommend you this because it has the best explanation matching to your requirements.

3>  [SQLite Tutorial for iOS: Making Our App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're a long way off what you need to be able to create the services you need for yourself and a relational database is unlikely to offer you value with what you described.

I can personally recommend using Parse.

It has a very simple interface, login authentication and integration with facebook etc are built in.

Saving objects to the cloud where other users can see it is even simpler than saving to a local file.

Parse.com

```
// Create a new Parse object
PFObject *post = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Post"];
[post setObject:@"Hello World" forKey:@"title"];

// Save it to Parse
[post saveInBackground];
```

and to retrieve (could be anyone on the app)

```
NSArray *postArray = [[PFQuery withObjectName:@"Post"] findObjects];
```

(I'm not an employee of parse or anything but it is really good if you don't know where to start)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn about different database types. If you are thinking about using MySQL, then ok, it is free and it is relational, so you have to study relational algebra, to become aware of the concepts of selection, projection, join, Descartes multiplication, relation and so on.

When you have a solid theoretical background, you can start to learn SQL syntax and will be able to work with databases, however, then you should learn how to plan a database by reading about normalisation, for instance, and then your should learn about more practical things, like the prevention of SQL injection.

And then, you will have to practice a lot.